# PHP DateTime modify to specifc date in month

Tags: php

I am trying to use the php DateTime objects modify function to modify he date to a specific date in the month i.e. 10th or 20th etc.

I have tried all of the following, none of which work:

```
$d = new DateTime();

$d->modify('10th day');
$d->modify('10th');
$d->modify('10th of this month');
$d->modify('10th of the month');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't know the year and month (if you do, use [`DateTime::setDate()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php)), one way to do this would like this:

```
$day = 10; // 10th of the month
$dt = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$dt->modify('+' . ($day - 1) . ' days');
```

I have a feeling that there's also a way to do it strictly through the constructor, but like you, I couldn't figure out the magic string.  Odd that "first day of the month" works, but "tenth day of the month" does not.

**Edit:** Apparently [it's impossible to do this through the constructor](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50249).  Even Rasmus suggests doing it this way instead.

Comment: How could it be - don't know a month but use "this" for it? :) Doesn't `date('n')` gives the same as `'this'` do?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [DateTime::setDate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setdate.php)

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate(2001, 2, 10);
```

Comment: is there a way to only set the day value?  I am doing this in a loop and so it means getting the current year day and month on each iteration otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$d = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$d->modify('+9 day');
```

PS: Nevertheless, I guess a better way to use

```
$cMonth = date('n');
$cYear = date('Y');
...
$d->setDate($cYear, $cMonth, 10);
```